# Read Nifti image with ITK in C++

Tags: vtk, itk

I am sorry if the question is primitive, but I can't figure the problem. I want to read nifti image in C++ using `ITK` libraries. I have used the code on Github: https://gist.github.com/rafamanzo/a3c258f4f74e898e9418. It is very simple code to read an image. Then I configured `ITK` into my project using `CMake`. The following is my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(MyProject)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/home/itk")
set(ITK_DIR "/home/itk/InsightToolkit-4.13.0/bin/")
set(VTK_DIR "/home/vtk/VTK-8.1.0/bin/")
find_package(ITK REQUIRED)
find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
if (ITKVtkGlue_LOADED)
  find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
  include(${VTK_USE_FILE})
else()
  find_package(ItkVtkGlue REQUIRED)
  include(${ItkVtkGlue_USE_FILE})
  set(Glue ItkVtkGlue)
endif()
include(${ITK_USE_FILE})
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})
add_executable(MyProject mainFile.cxx)
target_link_libraries(MyProject ${ITK_LIBRARIES})
```

"cmake .." is ran successfully.
But "make all" gives me an error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/vtk/VTK-8.1.0/bin/lib/libvtkRenderingOpenGL2.so', needed by 'MyProject'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/MyProject.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

And surprisingly, when I build the project from Eclipse, I got another error:

```
./bin/CMakeFiles/feature_tests.o: In function `main':
/home/MyProject/Debug/../bin/CMakeFiles/feature_tests.c:34: multiple definition of `main'
makefile:32: recipe for target 'MyProject' failed
./bin/CMakeFiles/3.6.2/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.o:/home/MyProject/Debug/../bin/CMakeFiles/3.6.2/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.c:540: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/vtk/VTK-8.1.0/bin/lib/libvtkRenderingContextOpenGL2-8.1.so
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [MyProject] Error 1
```

I am pretty sure that configuring `ITK` is easy, especially I have done it before, but to use ImageFileReader only. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to read an image you don't need *VTKGlue* part of `ITK` nor `VTK` itself. And the reported problem comes from `VTK`. If you want to keep `VTK` (to be used for something else?), you should fix it. Maybe you need to set `VTK_RENDERING_BACKEND` to `OpenGL2` or something similar. Try building some [VTK examples](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx) using your `VTK` to see if those examples build and run. That might point you more precisely to the problem.

Comment: I removed all instances of `VTK` from `CMakeLists.txt`, and I still got the same error `make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/vtk/VTK-8.1.0/bin/lib/libvtkRenderingOpenGL2.so', needed by 'MyProject'.  Stop.`
How I can solve this?

Comment: So, I tried to start it all over and I worked on HelloWorld tutorial found here: `https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/HelloInsight`
And I still get the same error message:
`$ make..
Scanning dependencies of target HelloWorld
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/HelloWorld.cxx.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/vtk/VTK-8.1.0/bin/lib/libvtkRenderingOpenGL2.so', needed by 'HelloWorld'.  Stop.`

Comment: You are barking up the wrong tree. Your ITK depends on VTK, and your VTK seems to be broken. Configure `/home/itk/InsightToolkit-4.13.0/bin/` in CMake, and set `Module_ITKVtkGlue` to `OFF`. Then rebuild ITK and your example.